# How can I correctly retrieve the current year value using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am pretty new in JavaScript and I have the following problem.

I have to retrieve the actual year (that is **2015**).

So I done in this way:

```
var oggi = new Date();
var year = oggi.getYear();
```

The problem is that the value of **year** variable is **115**, I think that it depend by the fact that it is calculated started by 1900, infact **1900 + 115 = 2015**

I know that I can add the **1900** value to the value retrieved into the **year** variable so I will obtain the desidered actual year value. But it seems to me a dirty solution. Can I do the same thing with a better solution?

Tnx

Comment: `getYear()` is deprecated precisely because of the behaviour you have identified. Use `getFullYear()` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`getFullYear()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getFullYear) to return a four-digit year:

```
var oggi = new Date();
var year = oggi.getFullYear();
```

In fact, the [`getYear()` method is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getYear) and, as described, returns 0 for any year less than 1900.

Answer (score 3):

Per [the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getYear), `getYear` does in fact return the current year - 1900. That's the documented behavior, shown in [the spec at B.2.4](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-B.2.40), so what you're doing is completely safe and reasonable. *However*...

The `getYear` method has been deprecated and replaced with [`getFullYear`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getFullYear), which returns a full four-digit year and is the preferred method now. `getFullYear` [was defined in ES5.1, section B.2.4](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.10). Per [the MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/29y2w2x3(v=vs.94).aspx), full year looks like it was supported as far back as IE6 ([compatibility table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4esdbwz(v=vs.94).aspx)).